# UTF8 Character Encoding using Twig - Symfony2

Tags: utf-8, twig

I'm getting data from a database and it's save in the table like this:

```
<p>Com o objetivo de conscientizar a popula&ccedil;&atilde;o
```

I used the filter *striptags* to remove the HTML tags but I can't change the text to UTF-8!

All my files are UTF-8 and they all have

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I tried

```
{{my_text|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')}}
```

and

```
{{my_text|raw|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')}}
```

My code is:

```
{% for noticia in noticias%}
    <a href="noticias/{{noticia.id}}">
      <div class="noticia">
          <img src='assets/temp/op1.jpg'>
        <h4 class="title">{{noticia.titulo|striptags}}</h4>
        <p class="text">{{noticia.texto|striptags|slice(0,180)|join(' ') ~ '…'}}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Can someone help me? Should I ask the database guy to fix it in the database?

Comment: Make sure your files and your database connection are also `UTF-8`

Comment: @DarkBee they are

Comment: Try `{{my_text|striptags|html_entity_decode|htmlspecialchars}}`. That is, replace `striptags` with `striptags|html_entity_decode|htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @DanielMartin I got: `Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "html_entity_decode" filter.`